# Sed find and replace a character in a patten using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following line and would like to replace the capital T with a blank space.

```
"2013-07-26T11:44:06.000+02:00"
```

I tried the following script but it did not work:

```
sed 's/^"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/T/""/g' file.csv
```

Comment: It can be easier to change the way the date is outputed. Can you change that?

Comment: `sed 's/T/ /' file` ?

Comment: `sed -r 's/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T/\1 /' file`?

Answer (score 5):

Since the date output won't generate any other T you can just go for :

```
sed 's/T/ /' file.csv
```

This will replace the first encountered T by a space.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `tr`?:

```
tr 'T' ' ' < test.csv
```

However, this is quite fragile as it would replace `T` also in other columns which doesn't contain dates. I gave this answer just as alternative for data which is not sensitive for that. For all other cases I would prefer @AvinashRaj's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
sed -r 's/^\"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(.)(.*)\"$/\"\1 \3\"/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '"2013-07-26T11:44:06.000+02:00"' | sed -r 's/^\"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})(.)(.*)\"$/\"\1 \3\"/g'
"2013-07-26 11:44:06.000+02:00"
```

Comment: No need to catch the 2nd group, just get up to `(.)` and then `/\1 /'` instead (also without `g`).

Comment: if you want to remove any character between date and time then go for my answer. If you want to remove only `T` then go for the above one.

Comment: Useless use of `echo` ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl it's just an example :-)

Comment: you can use `sed ... <<< '"2013-07-26T11:44:06.000+02:00"'` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr`

```
tr 't' ' ' <<< "2013-07-26T11:44:06.000+02:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would change the first 'T' to empty space if the line starts with a number.

```
sed '/^[0-9]/s/T/ /'
```